# laravel 5.3 connect with two databases

Tags: laravel

i have tow laravel 5.3 projects .. 
with different databases at same server appserv 3.8
the first database called final
the second one called accounting 
my problem thats the project with final database connect with accounting database and i dont need that .. 
when i refresh the page everything return back good .. 
in the .env file i didn't wrote anything about accounting database .. 
so why sometimes its connect to anther database by it self

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found
```

Comment: It doesn't mention which table?

Comment: the table im trying to add data to  and its not in the ather database